# can't forward port through openVPN using iptables on debian

Tags: iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding

I am trying to forward a port from public machine to another machine that is connected via VPN. that machine connects to internet via this VPN. I am using openvpn and iptables on debian.

the vpn works as expected, except i can't get port forwarding to work. i have reviewed many other questions on stackexchange, without success.

vpn client has static ip on vpn. and the public internet address is static as well.

forwarding is enabled...

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

the port on the client is open to the public machine, via vpn interface, but is not being forwarded from public machine. i have tried many variations of the iptables commands such as `-d <public ip>` and `-i eth0`, but can't figure what i am doing wrong.

```
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 14333 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.10:14333
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

$ iptables -t nat -L -v

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5252 packets, 328K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1471 85380 DNAT       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:14333 to:10.8.0.10:64333

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 50 packets, 2156 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 450 packets, 29316 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1998 packets, 122K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 4435  272K MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth0    10.0.0.0/8           anywhere
```

public interface is `eth0` and openvpn is `tun0`